# Tensorflow table lookup int->float

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given a 2D Tensor of unknown dimensions [?, ?] containing integers (representing classes), I would like to obtain a new Tensor of the same shape, but with the values replaced by floats taken from a lookup table (representing class weights).

For example:

```
inputs = [ [1,3,3], [2,4,2] ]
lookup table: {1: 0.2, 2: 0.25, 3: 0.1, 4: 0.45}
output: [ [0.2, 0.1, 0.1], [0.25, 0.45, 0.25] ]
```

I have tried to chain two lambda functions with tf.map_fn, iterating over every row, then over every element:

```
elem_iter = lambda y: unknown_lookup_function(y)
row_iter = lambda x: elem_iter(x)
weights = tf.map_fn(row_iter, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
```

but could not find a proper way of defining the lookup function.
Any advice on how to implement this behaviour ? Is there a native op that I could use instead of map_fn ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather):

The idea is that you store the lookup table as an array. At the index of `i`, you store the lookup value for input `i`. If your key is not integer but string, you would need to use [`index_table_from_file`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/index_table_from_file).

```
# Note I pad a dummpy element at index-0.
lookup_table = tf.constant([0, 0.2, 0.25, 0.1, 0.45])

inputs = tf.constant([ [1,3,3], [2,4,2] ])
output = tf.gather(lookup_table, inputs)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.run(output)

> 
  [[ 0.2         0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.25        0.44999999  0.25      ]]
```